# Anti-aliasing for Baked Textures

Tags: texture-baking

Is it still the only way to apply anti-aliasing to baked textures inside blender to bake it at a higher resolution and scale the texture down?

Answer (score 1):

Yes. As far as I know. I use Simple Bake though. Which is a $12 addon that helps to do this quickly, easily, and even lets you make presets for different image resolutions. It does a whole lot more and is the best time saver plugin I've ever gotten.